# How to trigger realtime database field in Google Cloud server (not in functions of Firebase)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I need to access to the realtime database of Firebase from my Google Cloud instance. I load libraries and try to do it in the same way as I do in Cloud Functions of Firebase but it doesn't trigger any event.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

functions.database.ref('stations/{stationID}/powerbanks/{powerbanksID}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  console.log("Eject: ", context.params.stationID, context.params.powerbanksID, change.after.exists())
})
```

I don't see any output when the database is modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Cloud Functions triggers only work in the Cloud Functions environment. They don't work on other node environments.

If you want to accomplish something similar in another environment, you'll need to [attach a normal listener to the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) and trigger your code from that.